# How to animate multiple divs to specific target location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, position, target

I have some problems making a function to set positions to some divs with jQuery animate. I made a quiz with jQuery and want the right "answered" draggable divs with an numeric id to automatically go to thier target position div with the same id. This is for the navigation (everytime only 12 questions are shown).

Html looks like this

```
<div id="container"> //floats left
    <div class="answer" id="1"></div> //droppables
    <div class="answer" id="2"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="3"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="4"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="5"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="6"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="7"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="8"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="9"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="10"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="11"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="12"></div>
</div>
<div id="container>
    <div class="drag" id="3"></div> //draggables are in random order
    <div class="drag" id="1"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="2"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="6"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="5"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="12"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="4"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="8"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="7"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="11"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="9"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="10"></div>
</div>
```

Each time someone drops the right draggable on the right droppable the id is stored in an array named `rightIds`.

Lets say rightIds is `array(0=>3, 1=>7 2=>9)`

I have also an array named `currentIds` which contains the ids that are now shown.
`currentIds` is now `array(0=>1 to 11=>12)`

I made this function:

```
function resetAnimation(currentIds, rightIds) {
    $.each(currentIds, function (index, value) {
        $.each(rightIds, function(ind, val) {
        console.log('currentIds value: ' + value);
        console.log('rightIds val: ' + val);
        if (val == value) {
            var target = $('#' + value + '.answer');
            console.log(target);
            var targetTop = target.offset().top;
            console.log('targetTop: ' + targetTop);
            var targetLeft = target.offset().left;
            console.log('targetLeft: ' + targetLeft);
            var drag = $('#' + value + '.drag');
            console.log(drag);
            var dragTop = drag.offset().top;
            console.log('dragTop: ' + dragTop);
            var dragLeft = drag.offset().left;
            console.log('dragLeft: ' + dragLeft);
            drag.animate({
                'top': -target.offset().top,
                    'left': -target.offset().left
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
}
```

But when I run it the drag divs are not going to the target position but to some other position. When I inspect the animated element the offset is the same as the target offset only with a "-" before the value. I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this problem.

thanx

Comment: Your html is invalid. The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique. (That doesn't mean you can't still implement some JS to achieve the desired effect, but I like to discourage use of invalid html.)

Comment: Why must it be unique if I want two divs look the same I give them the same id.

Comment: Why unique? Because that is [how the `id` attribute is defined](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id). Elements that are alike should be grouped via a common class. (As I already said, breaking this rule doesn't necessarily stop your page from working, but if you can achieve exactly the same effect _without_ using invalid html isn't that better?)

Comment: Ok but that is not the problem I have at the moment. But thanx for the info, I dindn't know that.

Comment: just on the above point of multiple ids, jquery will only ever pick up one object when using $('#id')

Comment: @Pete - Note that `$("div#id")` will get all divs with that id. Not that one should rely on such a construct since it is only necessary when the html is invalid...

Comment: I have reformatted your code which reveals some of your issue perhaps?  See that extra `});` that made its way in there?

Comment: NOTE: your code will be unreliable and unpredictable with duplicate IDs. Before you do ANYTHING ELSE, fix that and try again.

Comment: @nnnnnn i would never use that selector as it is slower than just using #id

Comment: Ok I know I have to keap the ids unique I will do that to set a letter before the number and use jquery to remove that letter. (thanx to the answer below) but that still doesn't solve the problem I have. As you can see my selector is $('#'+value+.answer) which means it search for the class as well. In my script i have lots of console.log() to show if it gets the right elements. And it does get the right elements.

Comment: @Pete - I saw that also, give jQuerys right to left selection, it selects all class "answer" and then inside that selects the one with the id specified - much MUCH slower than a simple id selector relatively speaking.

Comment: There is no variable val in my posted function anymore :P dunno who removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, if your drag element is positioned within the same offset parent, and both are absolutely positioned it should be as simple as replacing:

```
drag.animate({
  'top': -target.offset().top,
  'left': -target.offset().left
}, 3000);
```

With:

```
drag.animate({
  'top': target.offset().top,
  'left': target.offset().left
}, 3000);
```

If it is not absolutely positioned, then it is not quite the same as setting the offset, jQuery is clever enough to work out the correct relative positioning but animate does not use this same functionality. That failing you can use:

```
$drag.animate(
    { top: $target.position().top - $drag.position().top
    , left: $target.position().left - $drag.position().left }, 3000);
```

## Example usage

### Version 1 - jQuery matching

The HTML has been updated so that it is valid as correctly suggested by [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) (no duplicate ids):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="answer" id="answer-1"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-2"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-3"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-4"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-5"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-6"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-7"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-8"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-9"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-10"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-11"></div>
    <div class="answer" id="answer-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="drag" id="drag-3"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-1"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-2"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-6"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-5"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-12"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-4"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-8"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-7"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-11"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-9"></div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-10"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="get-answers">Get answers</a>
</div>
```

With this the JavaScript can be simplified to match up the drag-[id] to the answer-[id] and using the [position jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to move the drag elements to the correct places:

```
// Animates right answered draggables 
// to the right answers
function resetAnimation() {

    // Iterate over all of the drag elements
    $(".drag").each(function() {

        var $drag = $(this)

            // Get the id of the drag element
            // by dropping "drag-" off the front
          , id = $drag.attr("id").replace("drag-", "")

            // Find the matching answer
          , $target = $('#answer-' + id);

        // The animation code, position gives
        // the coordinates of the element relative
        // to the offset parent, subtract the original
        // position from the target position to get the
        // correct translation deltas
        $drag.animate(
            { top: $target.position().top - $drag.position().top
            , left: $target.position().left - $drag.position().left}, 3000);
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#get-answers").click(resetAnimation);
});
```

### Version 2 - Array matching

If you did want to stick to using the arrays to power this (I would use an object literal and treat the numbers as string ids personally), the modification to the code would be as follows:

```
// Animates right answered draggables 
// to the right answers
function resetAnimation(answered, correct) {

    // Iterate over all of the drag elements
    for(var id in answered) {

        if(answered[id] !== correct[id]) {

            var $drag = $("#drag-" + id)

                // Find the matching answer
              , $target = $('#answer-' + correct[id]);

            // The animation code, position gives
            // the coordinates of the element relative
            // to the offset parent, subtract the original
            // position from the target position to get the
            // correct translation deltas
            $drag.animate(
                { top: $target.position().top - $drag.position().top
                , left: $target.position().left - $drag.position().left}, 3000);

        }

    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#get-answers").click(function() {
        resetAnimation({
            "1" : "3",
            "2" : "2",
            "3" : "1"
        }, {
            "1" : "2",
            "2" : "3",
            "3" : "1"
        });
    });
});
```

---

The CSS I am using for these test case:

```
.answer { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px; 
    background: red; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px;
}
.drag { 
    position: relative;
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px; 
    background: green; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
}
.container { 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

[**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HM5zS/)

Comment: Thanx this is what I whas looking for. doing the target - the drag position. I also made my html valid now.

Comment: Nice one, I think that will make a lot of commenters above happy... It makes the world a better place! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css class not only to give style, but also to designate elements.

You can do something like

```
<div class="answer" id="answer-2" class="answer q2"></div>
<div class="answer" id="answer-3" class="answer q3"></div>
...
<div class="drag" id="question-2" class="q2"></div>
<div class="drag" id="question-6" class="q6"></div>
```

Now, you can match questions and answer using theyr class. For instance, for each question, get the class `var myClass = $(this).prop('class');` and find the matching answer `$("div.answer."+myClass);`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the simulate plugin that jQuery uses for testing to "simulate" drag and drop;

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

Some examples of use can actually be viewed in the tests:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/draggable/draggable_core.js

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/draggable/draggable_events.js